# How to run and debug a plugin without leaving the Intellij IDE?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing a costum intellij  plugin and it always open a new Intellij IDE automatically when I run this plugin.It is not very convenient to open a new IDE every time when I run/debug plugin.

Maybe there is a way to debug a plugin without leaving the IDE according to the doc blow:

[IntelliJ Platform SDK DevGuide](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/running_and_debugging_a_plugin.html)

> The IntelliJ Platform allows you to run and debug a plugin **without
>   leaving the IDE**. To run or debug the plugin from within IntelliJ IDEA,
>   you need a configured special profile (a Run/Debug configuration) **that
>   specifies the class to run**, VM parameters and other specific options.
>   In most cases, you can use the default Run/Debug configuration
>   profiles for your plugin projects.

so it seems that all you have to do is create a configured profile  that specifies the class to run.

[image]

but I can not find where to specifies the class.So if there is a way to debug without leaving the IDE?

Comment: The plugin cannot work just by itself. If you don't want to run the IDE, then make functional tests. Or use https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9552-hotswapagent

Comment: Seems that the description is not quite accurate, we will update it shortly. There is no need to specify the main class to run. But in any case you should start the [Plugin Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-plugin.html) that will launch new IDE instance which you will debug.

Comment: @Andrey launching new IDE instance is rellay inconvenient...

Comment: It is the only way to debug the plugin in a real IDE. Otherwise as mentioned by @Meo use functional tests.

Comment: @Andrey thansks your comment.Is there a way not to close the  new IDE instance automatically when you debug second time?

Comment: Use [hotswap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reloading-classes.html) not to relaunch the app on code change.

Comment: @Andrey  hotswap is really help!